# Strange folder under this pc with an mail name

Tags: windows, windows-10

My father did something with his PC, and I do not know what. He told me it has something to do with the backup he set up. But I have never come across such a folder.

When opening properties it shows location 127.0.0.1

On this image, you can see this folder:
[image: strange folder on windows]

What is this folder and how to create/remove it? also, where does it store its data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the "Media streaming" feature (UPnP Media Server) which can be enabled either through Windows Media Player, or through the (old) Control Panel.

Open Control Panel (`control.exe`) → "Network and Sharing Center" → "Media streaming options".

Comment: i will check it tomorrow. thanks so far.

Comment: It was the media streaming. He tried to stream music to the tv.

Answer (score 0):

Your father has set up an email account by creating a
free Bluewin e-mail address.
This address is inside the folder's name (`name@bluewin.ch`).

References:

- [Bluewin Webmail: Anleitungen](https://www.swisscom.ch/en/residential/help/internet/webmail.html)
- [Set up a Bluewin e-mail account and resolve problems](https://www.swisscom.ch/en/residential/help/internet/setting-up-bluewin-e-mail.html).

Comment: its not about the email address. its about this folder

Comment: You asked what it is, and my answer says that this is a Bluewin e-mail folder.

Comment: Your right, i may have asked the question wrong. I mean the type of folder.

Comment: I believe it's a normal folder used by the Bluewin app.